# Функция, которая выводит название месяца

Tags: php

Я понимаю как написать на JS функцию, которая выводит название месяца, но не понимаю синтаксис php

```js
let months = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];
let thisMonth = function (month) {
 return months[month];
};
let month = thisMonth(0);
console.log(month);
```

Через переменную, у меня были страшные ошибки и я попробывал простой функцией это сделать. Подскажите, как это сделать с помощью простой функции и с помощью переменной, которая является анонимной функцией(как у меня, в примере JS).

```php
$months = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];
function thisMonth($month) {
    return $months[$month];
}
```

**UPD:**
Есть такой код, который выводит посты. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как задать функцию `thisMonth`, которая должна вывести месяц, если ей передать цифру от 0 до 11. Я только изучаю PHP и не знаком с областями видимости. Я привык к тому как в js, что переменная берётся из ближайшей области видимости, но тут это не работает, как мне указать, что я хочу обновить переменную, которая в области видимости на 1 шаге назад?

```
function thisMonth($month) {
    global $months;
    return $months[$month];
}

$month = thisMonth(0);
echo $month;
```

```php
<?php
    $months = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];
    $categories = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT * FROM `articles`'); 
    $i = 0;
    while ($cat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($categories)) {
        $i++;
        if ($i == 1) { ?>
                <div class="post__intro first">
        <?php
        } else { ?>
            <div class="post__intro">
        <?php
        } ?>

    <a href="/category.php?id=<?php echo $cat['id'] ?>" class="post__intro__img">
        <img src="assets/img/zero-bs-crm.png" alt="">
    </a>
    <div class="post__intro__content">
        <a href="/category.php?id=<?php echo $cat['id'] ?>" class="post__intro__title">
            <span>
                <?php echo $cat['title'] ?>
            </span>
        </a>
        <div class="post__intro__info">
            <span class="post__intro__date">
                <?php 
                    $time = strtotime($cat['pubdate']);
                    function thisMonth($month) {
                        global $months;
                        return $months[$month];
                    }

                    $month = thisMonth(0);
                    echo $month;                
                ?>
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="post__intro__section">
                Новости
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="post__intro__text">
            <?php 
                $text = $cat['text'];
                $text = mb_substr($text, 0, 200);
                $text = rtrim($text, "!,.-");
                echo $text . ' …';
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

    <?php   
    }
?>
```

Comment: Добавь в функцию `global $months;` перед использованием. С переменной то же самое.

Comment: @РашенБеар а почему это нужно? Они что-ли не на одном уровне?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php 2 абзац

Comment: @РашенБеар понял вроде. Как же удобно в js, когда это не нужно указывать

Comment: И глобальная область видимости завалена всяким шлаком.

Comment: @u_mulder, посмотрите, я обновил вопрос, возможно понимаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете использовать данную конструкцию:

```php
$months = ['Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март', 'Апрель', 'Май', 'Июнь', 'Июль', 'Август', 'Сентябрь', 'Октябрь', 'Ноябрь', 'Декабрь'];
$month = function($monthIndex) use ($months) {
    return $months[$monthIndex];
};
echo $month(0);
```

Тут с помощью `use ($months)` вы говорите, что анонимная функция должна использовать глобальную переменную внутри себя.

Вызов простой: передаете в `$month(...)` индекс месяца.

Comment: спасибо, ваш ответ мне помог, подскажите, почему у меня объвление `global $months;` не помогало в моей функции? Я думаю что таким способом, как у меня тоже можно написать такую функцию, как у вас

Comment: Попробуй спросить у самого PHP, почему у тебя не помогало - и гадать не нужно будет

Answer (score 1):

Есть встроенная функция в языке, зачем это все? Массив явно лишний. Избегайте все писать в глобальную область видимости, и это не только про php.

```
function getMonth($monthIndex) {
    date("F", mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthIndex, 10));
}
```

Comment: Это тоже интересно, но я не понимаю как пользоваться синтаксисом PHP, в этом проблема, вот решение @mepihindeveloper помогло, но мне кажется, есть какой-то более гуманный способ написания этого

Comment: Ну можно кстати еще так 

function getMonth($indexMonth) {
   $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $monthNum);
   return $dateObj->format('F');
}

Comment: Почему избегать глобальную область видимости? Если я не собираюсь использовать кусок кода ещё раз, зачем мне его несколько раз объявлять?

Comment: Этот вопрос уже относится к принципам проектирования. Суть в том, что к глобальной переменной все имеют доступ, она не инкапсулирована, ее может кто угодно переписать. Например массив с месяцами.

Comment: прочитал про это, но мне ещё рано до такого. Я 2 день разбираюсь в PHP, поэтому я пишу такие функции

Comment: а ещё ситуация в том, что я не хочу изменять c помощью `setlocale()` язык для всего, но мне нужно выводить на русском месяц